# Document scanner doesn't detect the correct corners of the document. OpenCV Java & Python

Tags: python, java, opencv, android

## Context

I have a very good OpenCV document scanner written in Python and I need to translate it to Java, for an android application. *PS : The text is hidden in the documents because of the morphology close operations.*

I am using the same parameters on each version of the code, and yet, the results are different.

The current problem I am having is, after edge detection, I am unable to find the exact 4 corners of the document (in Java).

Here's pictures that should be self-explanatory :

[Corners in the Python version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvLBU.png)

[Corners in the Java version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIYIo.png)

This is especially weird since the edge detection reveals the exact same contours :

[Contours in the Python version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw9cf.png)

[Contours in the Java version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0BQO.png)

Both images went through the same process, that I'll explain here and send a part of the code :

1. Resizing
2. Close morphology operations to get rid of the text on the document
3. GrabCut() to get rid of the background
4. Grayscale, GaussianBlur, Canny and dilate

Java :

```
        // Method applications
        Imgproc.cvtColor(img, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(gray, blur, new Size(11,11), 0);
        Imgproc.Canny(blur, canny, 0, 200);
        Imgproc.dilate(canny, dilate, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(5,5)));
```

Python :

```
    # Transformation de l'image BGR en image "grayscale", nuances de gris
    # Utilisation de la méthode "GussianBlur()" afin de retirer le bruit d'image
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11,11), 0)
    
    # Utilisation des méthodes "canny()" et "dilate()" afin de détecter tout les bords de l'image
    canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 0, 200)
    dilate = cv2.dilate(canny, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5)))
```

My principle question is WHY would the results be different using the same parameters, once in Python, once in Java?

One thing I found is that on the particular image I sent, if instead of using the biggest contour I use the first one detected (so contours.get(O)), it works in Java.
But if I try to use the biggest contour, Python works, and Java doesn't.
Here's both code sample that are supposed to find to biggest contour :

Java :

```
        MatOfPoint largestContour = Collections.max(contours, new Comparator<MatOfPoint>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(MatOfPoint o1, MatOfPoint o2) {
                return Double.compare(Imgproc.contourArea(o1), Imgproc.contourArea(o2));
            }
        });
        List<MatOfPoint> page = new ArrayList<>();
        page.add(largestContour);
```

Python :

```
page = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:5]
```

The coordinates of those corners are really important because I need to do a perspective transform later on. If only one of those corners is wrong, the whole perspective is wrong!

Thank you for reading. Feel free to ask for more details about the parameters I use in some functions if you need it to help me.

Please help !

I tried the same methods with the same parameters in Python and Java, and the results are different.
One of the detected corners of the image is different in Java than Python, and that messes up the perspective transform.